# Strange behaviour with DENSE_RANK and IN

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, dense-rank

I'm experiencing some strange results when I combine a query containing `DENSE_RANK()` to produce the input to an `IN` clause.

To demonstrate I've seperated them out;

This query

```
select *
from ALL_QUOTE
where ID in ('G002WMLS')
```

returns 1 result:

```
ID        LongID  StartDate  EndDate
G002WMLS  67888   01/10/2011 30/11/2011
```

This query

```
select ID
from (

select LongId, ID, DENSE_RANK() over (partition by LongId order by end_date desc, substr(ID, 2, 7) desc, start_date desc) d
from WithoutPD
)

where d = 1 and LongId = '67888'
```

also returns 1 result:

```
ID
G002WMLS
```

however when I combine them both together:

```
select *
from ALL_QUOTE
where ID in (

select ID
from (

select LongId, ID, DENSE_RANK() over (partition by LongId order by end_date desc, substr(ID, 2, 7) desc, start_date desc) d
from WithoutPD
)

where d = 1

)
and LongId = '67888';
```

I end up with two results:

```
ID        LongID StartDate   EndDate 
G002MIMQ  67888  01/10/2010  30/09/2011 
G002WMLS  67888  01/10/2011  30/11/2011
```

I simply can't understand how `G002MIMQ` gets included in the results.  I'm using Oracle 11.2.0.1.0, however I understand this may be a generic SQL feature that I'm misunderstanding.

Hope you can shed some light on this strange problem.

Answer (score 1):

You've moved the `and LongID='67888'` outside of the where clause of the subquery.

Try this query instead...

```
select *
from ALL_QUOTE
where ID in (    
    select ID
    from (        
        select LongId, ID, DENSE_RANK() over (partition by LongId order by end_date desc, substr(ID, 2, 7) desc, start_date desc) d
        from WithoutPD        
    )        
    where d = 1
    and LongId = '67888'
);
```

**Edit**

```
select
    AllQuote.*
from
    AllQuote
        inner join
    (
        select ID
        from (
            select LongId, ID, DENSE_RANK() over (partition by LongId order by end_date desc, substring(ID, 2, 7) desc, start_date desc) d
            from WithoutPD
        ) t
        where d = 1
        and LongId = '67888'
    ) v
        on AllQuote.ID = v.ID
```

Comment: I originally thought that was the issue too but I extracted all results from that clause and used excel to check only `G002WMLS` exists in the results.

Comment: Are there any nulls in your data set? Does the query work if you replace the `in` with a join to the subquery (See edit above)

Comment: There are no null `ID`'s and if I join the `IN` within a subquery I get the two results (exactly the same).

Comment: I just tried your second edit and it now returns the correct result, I don't understand?

Comment: What is the data type of ID and LongID? It looks like a string - are there any spaces in that field? Can you convert it to an int?

Comment: It's a `VARCHAR2(8 Byte)`.  `ID` is actually longer than this example I truncated it before posting on here.